# Difference between idempotent and safe HTTP methods in REST APIs

Tags: java, rest, http, http-method, idempotent

How could the PUT method be idempotent but not safe? Can someone explain it out?

```
HTTP Method   Idempotent      Safe
OPTIONS        yes            yes
GET            yes            yes
HEAD           yes            yes
PUT            yes            no
POST           no             no
DELETE         yes            no
PATCH          no             no
```

Comment: Accepted this answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Safe method](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) doesn't change anything **internally** (resources)

> Safe methods are methods that can be cached, prefetched without any repercussions to the resource.

[Idempotent method](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) doesn't change anything **externally** (response)

> idempotent HTTP method is a HTTP method that can be called many times without different outcomes.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the specification:

> 4.2.2. Idempotent Methods
>
> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on
>   the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same
>   as the effect for a single such request. Of the request methods
>   defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe request methods
>   are idempotent.
>
> Like the definition of safe, the idempotent property only applies to
>   what has been requested by the user; a server is free to log each
>   request separately, retain a revision control history, or implement
>   other non-idempotent side effects for each idempotent request.
>
> Idempotent methods are distinguished because the request can be
>   repeated automatically if a communication failure occurs before the
>   client is able to read the server's response. For example, if a client
>   sends a PUT request and the underlying connection is closed before any
>   response is received, then the client can establish a new connection
>   and retry the idempotent request. It knows that repeating the request
>   will have the same intended effect, even if the original request
>   succeeded, though the response might differ.

(https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#idempotent.methods)